# Wireless keyboard Logitech K330 doesn't work

Tags: wireless, keyboard, logitech

I've installed Ubuntu (only base system, kernel 3.13, no graphic desktop) from Ubuntu minimal CD with my keyboard working. However after rebooting, it doesn't work at all. Keyboard itself *does* work though because I can enter BIOS before system starts.

Legacy BIOS for USB is enabled. Nothing special is present about keyboard at BIOS setup.

Removing and inserting dongle exercised and doesn't make a change.

For information, this is the output form `lsusb` and `dmesg`.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep Logitech`:

```
[ 2.242089] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem on Ubuntu 15.04. Bios is working (F11, F12, DEL), then ubuntu is starting and i have to enter my disk encryption password -> keyword does not work.

see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/975198

Workaround: I use a cable based keyboard to enter the disk encryption password. After entering the disk encryption password the wireless keyboard works and i can logon with it.